# Forcing INF and NaN to 0 in VB.NET Excel Interop

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

I am creating a report in my ASP.NET application. The report outputs to Excel using the Excel interop. Some calculations in the report cause Excel to display "INF" or "NaN". I want to force these calculations to zero so that the report displays zero and NOT "INF" or "NaN".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to do this on the Excel side, after the value is populated as "Inf" or "NaN"?  If so, running this VBA code will replace all your non-numeric values with 0.

```
Sub fixValues()
    Dim areaToSearch As Range, cell As Range
    Set areaToSearch = Sheet1.Range("A1:A50")
    For Each cell In areaToSearch
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False Then
            cell.Value = 0
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```